# Which terminals can gnome-terminal emulate?

Tags: gnome-terminal

gnome-terminal can emulate "xterm" and "xterm-256color".

Which other terminals, as described under "/usr/share/terminfo", can gnome-terminal emulate?

Is there any way to find out (apart from sias)?

I've tried running a "strings" equivalent over "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal" and "/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server", but no clues there.

Comment: Please describe what you need, and it will be easier to help you. And please see the difference between how the shell `bash` works (what it can emulate), what `xterm` can emulate (old physical terminals) and what `gnome-terminal` can do.

Comment: I would like to use a terminal definition that has a status line, à la: tput hs ; tput eslok ; tput wsl ; tput fsl ; tput tsl. Neither "xterm" nor "xterm-256color" have these capabilities. So yes, I wan  to find out what gnome-terminal can do.

Comment: I don't think gnome-shell "emulates" those other terminals.  It is just that its capabilities are a superset of them as it is based on them.  For instance, xterm-256color is a superset of xterm which is itself a superset of vt100.

Comment: GNOME Terminal (in fact, the underlying VTE widget) implements one hardwired behavior, which reasonably resembles xterm's behavior for the vast majority of uses and is reasonably well described by the `xterm-256color` terminfo entry. I really don't think it supports a status line (having been a developer of this project, this really doesn't ring a bell). It supports a scrolling region which, to some extent, can be useful if an app wants to implement something like a status bar.

Comment: The terminal emulator `terminator` can be installed with `sudo apt install terminator` in Ubuntu and it has a status line. The default info in that line is 'user@hostname current-dir widthxheight', and I think you can modify it.

Comment: Most of the graphical terminals do a status line by stuffing it in the title bar, although some have made that a separate control code.

Comment: I tried `terminator`. Unfortunately, "TERM=xterm-256color".

Comment: `xterm-256color` reports that it has a status line `tput -Txterm-256color hs`. However, the escape code for "to status line"  A) doesn't work B) looks wrong: `tput -Txterm-256color tsl` gives "^[[2$~^[[1$}^[[%i%p1%d`"; "%i%p1%d" looks like C printf conversion specifications, "%i" for integer, "%p" for a pointer, "%d" for a decimal.